# Gnuplot: coloring area inside uncertainty

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a bunch of 2D points, each point comes with an error in the x coordinate and in the y coordinate. I don't like how `with xyerrorbars` shows the points because these are measurement that will be more and more dense.

I'd like if these points could form a colored surface, like these kind of plots:
http://www-cdf.fnal.gov/physics/new/hdg/Results_files/results/hwwmenn_120224/figures/limit/cdf4g17july2011.gif

Do you know if there's there a striagth forward way in Gnuplot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that your data file is in the following format:

```
x y sx sy
```

where sx and sy are the standard deviations in x and y.  You can use the `filledcurves` option to plot:

```
plot 'data.dat' using 1:($2+2*$4):($2-2*$4) title '+/- 2 SD', \
     'data.dat' using 1:($2+$4):($2-$4) title '+/- 1 SD', \
     'data.dat' title 'data'
```

`help filledcurves` gives you a couple of examples.

Comment: Thank you! so to plot a file with the y-errorbar (in a file with coloumns `x y sy`) I used  `plot 'data.dat' u 1:($2-$3):($2+$3) filledcurves below x1`